# Writing a Shell script to tail and gzip a log file

Tags: shell-script, tail, gzip

I'm trying to make a script that can tail log files from a remote server to my local directory. **tail -F** is what I'm using but after piping it with **gzip**, nothing happens although a local copy of the log file is created.

**Update**:
The script runs but it can't reach the gzip command since I have to type ctrl+c to end the tailing. Thus it ends the script without even zipping it.

```
to_Tomcat(){
        # tail log file -> zips it using gzip 
        tail -F /sampleRemoteDirectory/logs/tomcat/sample.log > "$TomcatLogFileName"-Tomcat.log | gzip "$TomcatLogFileName"-Tomcat.log
        echo ""
        echo "...tailing the log file and saving it as $TomcatLogFileName-JBoss.log.gz"
        echo ""
    }

to_Tomcat TomcatLogFileName
                sleep 10            
ret=$?

# last note before the user has to exit the shell script

echo ""
echo "Saved file: $TomcatLogFileName-Tomcat.log.gz"
```

Comment: You're piping to `gzip`, which you shouldn't be doing. Change the `|` to `;`.

Comment: Thank you, I'll update the script and run it using your suggestion.

Comment: The script runs but it can't reach the gzip command since I have to type **ctrl+c** to end the tailing. Thus it ends the script without even zipping it.

Comment: If you want to take a snapshot of the end of the log file, try something like `timeout 60s tail -F /sampleRemoteDirectory/logs/tomcat/sample.log`, which will run tail for a minute.

Comment: Noted @Mark,  I will add updates once the suggestion satisfies the query :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tail -f` is meant to be interactive, other than `timeout` you should try `tail -100` (100 or whatever) to catch last lines.

main part would be

```
tail -100 /whatever/sample.log | gzip > /whatever/sample.log.gz
```